# Rewrite URL using PHP

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Following is the Folder Structure of my PHP Project

```
PHPProject (Root)
-->Admin/
-->Config/
-->File1.php
-->File2.php
--> ..
--> ..
-->.htaccess
-->File10.php
```

I would like to enable RewriteURL for the project that can be accessed in the following manner.

**Rule 1:**
My Domain should always be accessed with www.mydomain.com. If someone tries to access as `http://mydomain.com` i will have to rewrite the URL to `http://www.mydomain.com`. For which I am using the following rule on my htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mydomain\.com [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

**Rule 2:**
I would like to have a specific URL that points to a page:

`http://www.mydomain.com/username` to rewrite to `http://www.mydomain.com/file4.php?name=username`

**Rule 3:**

I am able to get the first rule to work properly with the above information on .htaccess file, but the problem is I have to hardcode the domain name on it. Would it be possible to specify a generic (regex) so that the rule applies to multiple domain?

**Question:**
I require help to combine Rule 1 + Rule 2 + Rule 3 altogether as rules on my .htaccess file.

Could someone please help me acheive this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Rule 1:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(domain1|domain2|domain3|domain4)\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

or:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain1\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain2\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain3\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain4\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

---

### Rule 2

`http://www.mydomain.com/username`

to

`http://www.mydomain.com/file4.php?name=username`

```
RewriteRule ^username$ /file4.php?name=username [QSA,NC,L]
```

and if you want to make it generic (with alphanum chars):

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)$ /file4.php?name=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

---

### Rule 3

Get all together:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(domain1|domain2|domain3|domain4)\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)$ /file4.php?name=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Hope this helps.

### Two hints:

Please try to use the `RewriteLog` directive: it helps you to track down such problems:

```
# Trace:
# (!) file gets big quickly, remove in prod environments:
RewriteLog "/web/logs/mywebsite.rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 9
RewriteEngine On
```

---

My favorite tool to check for regexp:

http://www.quanetic.com/Regex (don't forget to choose ereg(POSIX) instead of preg(PCRE)!)

Answer (score 0):

If you only need it for http, this should do.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}!^(www\.¦$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

And, For the rest you can use the `Front Controller Pattern`.

[Idea of `Front Controller Pattern` is redirects all your request to a php file and decide from there]

Follow the following urls, then if you have any question, you can ask :)

http://www.phppatterns.com/docs/design/the_front_controller_and_php

http://onlamp.com/pub/a/php/2004/07/08/front_controller.html?page=2